# Can I get a JTextField above an JEditorPane but below a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtabbedpane

I'm working on a simple web browser that has tabs. I'm having alot of trouble adding a textfield below the tabbedpane, exactly like it is in chrome. Heres what I have so far:
     public class Browser
     {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panelTop;
    private JEditorPane editor;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTextField field;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton home;
    private URL url;
    private JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private ImageIcon nt = new ImageIcon("./Icons/newTab.jpg");
    private ImageIcon cl = new ImageIcon("./Icons/close.png");
    private JButton newTab = new JButton(cl);
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private int tabCounter = 0;
    private Dimension dim = new Dimension(nt.getIconWidth()+2, 
            nt.getIconHeight()+2);
    public Browser()
    {
        initComponents();

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("TeslaNet Browser");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    menuBar.add(file);
    file.add(exit);

    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    panelTop = new JPanel();
    frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panelTop);
    panelTop.add(field);
    panelTop.add(button);
    panelTop.add(home);
    panelTop.add(newTab);

    newTab.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            initComponents();
        }
    });
    newTab.setToolTipText("New Tab");
    newTab.setPreferredSize(dim);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(topPanel);
    topPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panelTop.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private void initComponents()
{
    try
    {
        url = new URL("http://www.reddit.com");
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException mal)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mal);
    }

    try
    {
        editor = new JEditorPane(url);
        editor.setEditable(false);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ioe);
    }

    scroll = new JScrollPane(editor, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    field = new JTextField(14);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
       public void run()
       {
           field.setText(url.toString());
       }
    });

    button = new JButton("Go");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                editor.setPage(field.getText());
            }

            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe);
            }
        }
    });

    home = new JButton("Home");
    home.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try
            {
                url = new URL("http://www.thissongissick.com");
                field.setText(url.toString());
            }

            catch(MalformedURLException mal)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mal);
            }

            try
            {
                editor.setPage(field.getText());
            }

            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe);
            }
        }
    });        
    JPanel tab = new JPanel();

    JButton closeButton = new JButton(nt);
    closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            tabbedPane.remove(tabbedPane.getTabCount()-1);
        }
      });
    closeButton.setPreferredSize(dim);
    closeButton.setToolTipText("Close");


    JLabel tabLabel = new JLabel("Tab " + (++tabCounter));
    System.out.print(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
    tab.setOpaque(false);

    tab.add(tabLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    tab.add(closeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    tabbedPane.addTab(null, editor);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(tabbedPane.getTabCount()-1, tab);
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an compilable example with all fields and initializations.

Comment: Please note that your problem almost certainly lies with the layout manager not the individual components so I've edited your tags

Comment: I've added the initializations plus the other methods used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example. I didn't want to try and guess which variables are for which component, so I cam up with a similar example. What you need to do do is put everything you want in a tab, *inside* the panel for the tab. So basically each panel will have its *own* text field and editor pane

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Browser1 {
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private final JButton add;
    int i = 1;

    public Browser1() {
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.add(new JScrollPane(createTabbedPanel()), "Tab " + i);

        add = new JButton("Add Tab");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                i++;
                tabbedPane.add(new JScrollPane(createTabbedPanel()), "Tab " + i);
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Browser");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        buttonPanel.add(add);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTabbedPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField field = new JTextField(50);
        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));

        panel.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Browser1();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This actually helped me realize a major flaw in the code as well